# Does `next()` move or clone elements?

Tags: rust

I'm reading the [Chapter 13 of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-03-improving-our-io-project.html). It says that `clone`ing strings is less efficient than accessing them through an iterator (i.e. `next()`). Comparing the following examples, I've got two questions:

- Does `args.next()` move or clone the string into `query` and `filename`?
- If it was a move, it would transfer the ownership from something in `env::args()` to `query`, wouldn't this break other code? If it was a clone, why could be it more efficient than cloning the string directly?

---

Definition:

```
struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}
```

**Inefficient Version**

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();  
    let config = Config::new(&args)
}

impl Config {
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        // [...]
        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();
        // [...]
    }
}
```

**Better Version**

```
fn main() {
    let config = Config::new(env::args())
}

impl Config {
    fn new(mut args: std::env::Args) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        args.next();

        let query = match args.next() {
            Some(arg) => arg,
            None => return Err("Didn't get a query string"),
        };

        let filename = match args.next() {
            Some(arg) => arg,
            None => return Err("Didn't get a file name"),
        };
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `args.next()` move or clone

Start by looking at the function signature for `Iterator::next`:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

`next` transfers ownership of whatever type `Self::Item` is to the caller. It has no extra restrictions on `Self`, but it can modify the inner properties of the iterator.

Next, inspect the inputs and outputs of the specific iterator. For example, this one always returns strings, but has no input values:

```
struct Greet;

impl Iterator for Greet {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(String::from("hello"))
    }
}
```

In this case [`Args` defines `Item` to be a `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html), so each value from calling `next` is an `Option<String>`.

We know that `String` requires an allocation. However, since we can't provide any arguments for `env::args()` to take allocation from, only two possibilities exist:

1. The iterator allocates the value.
2. Some kind of global state is being modified behind the scenes.

Rust generally *abhors* global state, so anything that actually changes global state is going to be really common (printing to stdout) or marked with Big Warning Text.

Checking the documentation, we see no such Big Warning Text, so it is safe to assume that the iterator allocates.

You can check this by iterating through it twice; you'll see the same values repeated. The argument list is not secretly mutated underneath you.

---

Even though this iterator allocates strings, it's *still* more efficient to use the iterator's value directly. When you collect into the vector, you are allocating memory for the vector. You also then clone the value inside the vector again to use it. Both of those allocations are unneeded.

A middle-efficiency version would be to use references to the items in the vector, specifically a `&str`:

```
let query = &args[1];
let filename = &args[2];
```

This still has the "overhead" of allocating the vector, which may or may not be needed outside of this function.

---

I like being overly fancy, so I might write something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let config = Config::new(std::env::args().skip(1));
}

impl Config {
    fn new<I, S>(args: I) -> Result<Config, &'static str> 
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = S>,
        S: Into<String>,
    {
        let mut args = args.into_iter();

        let query = args.next().ok_or("Didn't get a query string")?;
        let filename = args.next().ok_or("Didn't get a file name")?;

        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

The `ok_or` is generally useful, as is making the iterator type generic and skipping the program name outside of `Config::new`. This allows for testing `Config` without having an actual argument string.

The `Into<String>` is purely showing off.

Comment: Two follow-up: 1) how do one know the function is not making a copy internally from the signature? Because it doesn't require Item to be Copy? 2) moving ownership means Args doesn't own the arguments anymore. Isn't this a big side effect that I have to remember throughout the project? I guess I'm just verifying I understand how it works, setting aside whether it's a good practice.

Comment: @qweruiop ah, I slightly misread your question. Let me fix up my answer.

Comment: But why is using references only middle-efficient? When reference items, no allocation for items is needed at all, no?

Comment: @qweruiop because you are still allocating the vector for no reason.